# Angular 1.3.20 improper binding in IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I've got an angular app in version 1.3.20 and the normal {{ }} binding syntax doesn't load for this field. Instead what happens is I see first table cell as `{{item.subItemId}}`.

### app.js

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('/bootstrap', function (data) {
        var brandConfig = setupBrand();
        window.config = angular.extend(window.config, {brand: brandConfig}, data);
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app'), ['app']);

    });
});
```

### view.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items track by item.id" ng-show="!ctrl.loading">
    <td class="table-default__cell--status">
       <item-status item="item"></item-status>
    </td>
    <!-- renders as  {{item.subItemId}} instead of actual value -->
    <td>{{item.subItemId}}</td>
    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
    <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

When I switch `<td>{{item.subItemId}}</td>` to be `<td ng-bind="item.subItemId"></td>` that table cell correctly renders, but then the next column has the same problem and renders as `{{item.description}}` instead of the actual value.

### important notes

- This improper binding happens only in IE11 and only for two data columns in the entire application. The other example was identical so I left it out. IE 9 and 10 don't have this problem.
- duplicate question, but doesn't supply a solution to the root problem - [AngularJS template variable not working/displaying in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729833/angularjs-template-variable-not-working-displaying-in-ie11).

## Things I have tried to adjust

- IE compatibility meta tag. Currently, this value is `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`
- upgrading angular from 1.3.16 to 1.3.20. I was hoping for a magic fix here, but the latest bug patch is a good thing nonetheless.
- html validation of the view file. No improper tags were found.
- Fixing all console.log methods to use `$log` instead

Comment: what is `adjustment`? perhaps try changing the `track by`?

Comment: @charlietfl, apologies for the confusion. `adjustment.item` was a typo from me when extracting any identification from the code. It is corrected now.